# Use custom SNI for Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, sni

I have an app back-end on a server it has many users in China and it uses websocket, I'm doing some tests to bypass GFW's blockage of SNI, we can connect to Cloudflare Websocket websites in China, but then the whole domain gets blocked after a few days!

So what I am doing right now is this setup:

```
Address: another domain using cloudflare doesn't matter which one
Host: Your own subdomain, like sub.example.com, which has an A record to your own server's ip
SNI: Your own subdomain, like sub2.example.com, which doesn't need any record.
```

So through some tests I figured out I could use any subdomain of my own domain for SNI without any problem (I honestly don't understand why it works) and for a while the domain didn't get blocked but then it suddenly did.

So I'm looking for a way to use another SNI, but I can't figure it out! I thought about using a CNAME from another domain to `sub2.example.com` but that didn't make sense to me either, I also have thought about hosting a server that can handle SNI something between that second domain and Cloudflare but I'm still lost.